# PreparedStatement selecting one row less then actual in java

Tags: java, sql

I have the following query by using which I want to select some rows from the database from two tables:

```sql
select u.person_id,u.email_address
  from xx_e_portal_users u, xx_dummy_person_prod per
  where u.person_id = per.person_id
    and u.email_address like '%john%'
```

When I run this query in Toad, I am getting two rows. When I run the same query using prepared statement, I am only getting one row.

Here is the Java code that I am using to select rows from the database:

```
activeUsers = "select u.person_id,u.email_address  from xx_e_portal_users u,  xx_dummy_person_prod per where u.person_id = per.person_id and u.email_address like '%john%'";

connection = getConnection();
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(activeUsers,
    ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
//ps.setString(1, "15");
//ps.setInt(1, 7);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
rs.last();

count = rs.getRow();//ERROR:Actual rows - 1, always          
rs.beforeFirst();
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Aren't rows indexed starting from 0?

Comment: i have also used while loop to print the result set values i am still getting one less

Comment: @Iamsomeone No, it's not what you would expect, but rows are numbered from 1, not 0. See API doc of [`ResultSet.getRow()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getRow--).

Comment: It's only happening with the above query where i select data from two tables. when i select rows from one table i am getting correct result

Comment: When i create a view from the above query mentioned in my question then it's working correctly

Answer (score 3):

Don't do this:

```
rs.last();
```

It will move the cursor of the query to the last row, so the result will be only one row. Note that not all result sets are scrollable, so you can't always jump arbitrarily to the end and back to the beginning.

However, you must do:

```
rs.next();
```

before you get the first row. Normally you do this in a loop:

```
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    // Get the columns of the current row
    String personId = rs.getString(1);
    String emailAddress = rs.getString(2);

    // Do whatever needs to be done with these values
}
```

Comment: I am using rs.beforeFirst() too after rs.last(). Using last function to get the total rows.